# Spring bean autowire for testing

Tags: java, spring, testing, autowired

I have many spring services with this autowire:

```
@Autowired
private SmartCardService smartCardService;
```

I need a dummy class for testing and I defined this class extending the original:

```
@Service
public class DummySmartCardService extends SmartCardService{
    ...
}
```

How can I be sure that all autowire will take the dummy instead of original service without changing all Autowired annotation?

Thanks.

Comment: It's the reason why I prefer XML configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the @Primary annotation. See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Load your `DummySmartCardService` bean from a test version of your application context file instead so that no changes to the code under test are necessary

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-services.xml"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the @Resource annotation or a @Qualifier, With @Qualifier which discriminates bean types:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("testing")
private SmartCardService smartCardService;

@Service
@Qualifier("testing")
public class DummySmartCardService extends SmartCardService{
    ...
}
```

Or with @Resource which uses by-name semantics:

```
@Resource("dummySmartCardService")
private SmartCardService smartCardService;


@Service("dummySmartCardService")
public class DummySmartCardService extends SmartCardService{
    ...
}
```

Theoretically you could use `@Qualifier("beanName")` but it is discouraged.

But it think would be better if you had a Spring profile to load only test related stubs in your tests:

```
@Service
@Profile("test")
public class DummySmartCardService extends SmartCardService{
    ...
}

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:services.xml"})    
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestSuite{
    @Autowired
    private SmartCardService smartCardService;
}
```

Comment: @ŁukaszLech yeah, I prefer xml sometimes but there is nothing wrong with using annotations knowing how to use them.

Comment: The problem is that I need to change ALL @Autowired annotation

Comment: @ŁukaszLech I think that with Resource annotation you need only change one isn't it? I think using XML is too verbose sometimes: Would you use Spring MVC with XML too?

Comment: @mael with XML you write it once, with annotations you modify code each time to run the tests, at least in that case.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech and with annotations too in that case, you just need to plan it better ;)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should take a look at [Springockio](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) for proper and rather easy mocking of Spring beans.

You can replace your bean with a mock or wrap with a Spy this way:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class,
locations = "classpath:/context.xml")
public class SpringockitoAnnotationsMocksIntegrationTest extends 
                                AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @ReplaceWithMock
    @Autowired
    private InnerBean innerBean;

    @WrapWithSpy
    @Autowired
    private AnotherInnerBean anotherInnerBean;
    ....
}
```

This not only is a clean way (you **do not** need to change the code being tested by adding qualifiers or profiles) but also allows you to use the capabilities of [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for mocking, verifying and spying which is great.

Comment: Great in theory, in practice this project has tons of annoying bugs.